# Cannot access 'android.app.Application' which is a supertype of 'com.theapp.name.Application' - FCM

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've followed the guide to implement FCM and everything works fine except the onbackgroundMessage handle so I started to read carefully the steps I had to follow and noticed the class Application I created complains about

> **"Cannot access 'android.app.Application' which is a supertype of
> 'com.theapp.name.Application'. Check your module classpath for missing
> or conflicting dependencies"**

The case is that the official guide to implement FCM with flutter suppose that the app use Java but my app was created with Kotlin. So I did some search and created the Application class in the Kotlin folder where is MainActivity too and I think there's something messed up because the **io.flutter.pluggins** is in the java folder.
Also in AndroidManifest.xml in the line:

```
android:name=".Application"
```

I get this error: **Application must extend android.app.Application**
and on the line:

```
    android:name=".MainActivity"
```

The same warning: **MainActivity must extend android.app.Activity**

Anyone can help me with this, please?